# get substring from string Java(Android)

Tags: java, regex

Could you help me with this problem? I have String like this:

```
<p class="youtube_sc mobile "><a href="vnd.youtube:bMHJODdp7-U" title="YouTube video player"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bMHJODdp7-U/hqdefault.jpg" /><span class="play-button-outer" title="Click to play video"><span class="play-button"></span></span></a></p>
```

And I need to get only what will be after "*youtube:*" in this example this part of line:
**bMHJODdp7-U** 
I use this code of my example:

```
String path = strin.replaceAll(".*(youtube:\\S+)", "$ title");
```

Where strin is the String line. But this code only replace what I need to " title" 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```
^.*?youtube:([^"]+).*$
```

and replace it by:

```
$1
```

**Code:**

```
String path = strin.replaceFirst("^.*?youtube:([^\"]+).*$", "$1");
//=> bMHJODdp7-U
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH0tF1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Explanation - `youtube:(.*?)\"` matches for text in between `youtube:` and `"`

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<p class=\"youtube_sc mobile \"><a href=\"vnd.youtube:bMHJODdp7-U\" title=\"YouTube video player\"><img src=\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bMHJODdp7-U/hqdefault.jpg\" /><span class=\"play-button-outer\" title=\"Click to play video\"><span class=\"play-button\"></span></span></a></p>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("youtube:(.*?)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
bMHJODdp7-U
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression to

```
(?:youtube:)(\S+)(?:")
```